# How To Replace Data From New Data Coming From Another .blend?

Tags: materials, objects, linked-data, append, data-blocks

Here's a simple example,

1. I have a .Blend with 50 objects, all *appended* inside my .Blend, they each have their own materials. Now I created my scene with those assets and did some work etc...
2. My client gave me an updated version of their assets *with new materials*, now I need to replace every material data in my scene with this newly updated material data, both data have the same name.

Is there a smart way to replace data in blender?
I know that I should have linked the assets at the first place, but sadly this is not possible (the client asked to avoid linked data in this case)

While I could doodle around in python, I'm sure there's something already existing to do that? Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a python script with a name comparison.
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.user_remap